# dismissing a UIAlertView programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I need help on dismissing a UIAlertView programmatically. Currently I have this

`UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title"        message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];`

then later on I call this

```
[alert1 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: when you call "`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex`", is "`alert1`" not null?

Comment: Are you calling `show` and `dismiss` in the same block of code? This will not work because `show` needs time to execute.

Comment: No the dismiss is called conditionally much later on.

Comment: How do you get to "later on"? You should tell us more of what you're doing...

Comment: @Nick P delegate: self & both button references are set to nil, so dismissWithClickedButtonIndex will have nothing to reference. You need to set at least one title value for otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to set two things.

**1. include your .h file  :** `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`

**2. please follow below implementation...**

```
   UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [alert1 show];
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) withObject:alert1 afterDelay:1.0];
```

**the dismiss method will be...**

```
-(void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem too.
In my case, for some reason calling:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

didn't work always (yes, even calling it on UI thread and yes, alert != nil), instead simply setting the animated flag to YES it worked:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Maybe it's an Apple bug...

Answer (score 3):

you should display it first:

```
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert1 show];
```

then in delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex==0){
     // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: that delegate method will only be called if the O.P. sets his delegate properly when he creates his alert.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have a displayed it, like you described.I tried this i get the same results. Nothing happens.

Comment: have you set alert1's delegate?

Comment: Yes but I don't know what to put in it.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you called is correct.
I guess the alert1 is nil when your call the method dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:

Try to check your variable alert1.

Comment: i just checked and its not nil when i call the method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method **-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:** instead—it gets called once the alert view’s been removed from the screen, OR better approach is , use a background thread, e.g. with **-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:**, to handle whatever processing you need to do.