# Can an AlertView be timed out in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uialertview, nstimer

I want to know if it is possible for an AlertView to time out if it has been visible on the screen for a certain period of time without receiving any acknowledgement from the user, and if so, how?  Is there a way for the AlertView object be linked with an NSTimer object?

My basic AlertView code is the following:

```
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                      message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I implemented in one of my apps

Inside the @interface declare your objects so you can keep track of them and add the  if required

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *myAlert;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

In your code where you need to launch the alert add the following

```
self.myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"TEST" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(cancelAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[self.myAlert show];
```

Somewhere in your code add next function to dismiss the alert and invalidate the NSTimer

```
- (void)cancelAlert {
[self.myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}
```

Also remember to invalidate the timer if a button is touched.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
[self.myTimer invalidate];
// Process pressed button
}
```

It may need some tweaks for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a)

For example with a dispatch_after block, like this:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:message.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
});
```

---

If you want to use a NSTimer just save the `UIAlertView` in an instance variable so you can access it from within the timer method.

Comment: There's a risk that the alert view could be released by the time this is called if the user has dismissed it manually. Better to use an NSTimer, which can be invalidated.

Comment: It might be released, but not deallocated. Important difference. The block retains the alert. After the block is finished the block will release the alert. And only after that the alert will be deallocated.

Comment: If it's been removed from the superview it would be. I don't think the block will retain the alert, will it?

Comment: A block retains all the objects that are referenced inside the block.

Comment: Right you are.  Disregard.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a category for `UIAlertView` and add an observer which listens out and if it is triggered, removes itself:

```
@implementation UIAlertView (Cancellable)

+ (instancetype)cancellableAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                      message:(NSString *)message
                                     delegate:(id)delegate
                            cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                            otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:delegate
                                              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    if (otherButtonTitles != nil)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
        for (NSString *buttonTitle = otherButtonTitles; buttonTitle != nil; buttonTitle = va_arg(args, NSString*))
        {
            [alertView addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
        }
        va_end(args);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:alertView selector:@selector(removeAlertView:) name:@"AlertsShouldBeCancelledNotification" object:nil];

    return alertView;
}

- (void)removeAlertView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Then you could create an `NSTimer` in your main class and have it trigger the notification when the selector is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSTimer to call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` and invalidate it if the user clicks in time. Using dispatch_after risks sending the message to a released instance if the user has dismissed it already.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  Can you please show me how you'd use an NSTimer object to call dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated in conjunction with an AlertView?

Comment: I was actually incorrect in the statement that the alertview could be deallocated before dispatch_after executed. However, if you still want to do it with an NSTimer, check out `+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: [dismissing a UIAlertView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416825/dismissing-a-uialertview-programmatically) . Using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is much more elegant than building and tearing down a timer, in my opinion.