# Dismiss a UIAlertController with the Keyboard's Return Key

Tags: objective-c, ios8, keyboard, dismiss, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to dismiss a UIAlertController's alert window via the keyboard return key? In my project, the return key only dismisses the keyboard, but the alert window stays on the screen until I press the alert's 'ok' button.

Comment: You can use this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416825/dismissing-a-uialertview-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

This should be the standard behavior, but i had the same problem.

It was caused by having two buttons (ok and cancel) with style UIAlertActionStyleDefault. Once I changed one of them to UIAlertActionStyleCancel, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try some custom notification like below inside viewDidLoad,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(dismissit)                                                name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                          object:nil];

-(void)dismissit{
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps. Please kindly provide your feedback whether it solved your problem.